# Converting a nested tuples into nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionaries that have as their values some tuples:

```
dic1 = {
    'persuaded ': [[('teacher', '6'), ('group', '5'), ('man', '5'), ('girl', '5')]], 
    'removed ': [[('apple', '5'), ('makeup', '4'), ('trash', '4'), ('stain', '4')]]
}
```

What I need to do is to convert the nested tuples into dictionaries, so that I can compare it with other similar lists afterwards using the keys. The ideal outcome would be something like:

```
dic2 = {
    'persuaded ': [{'teacher': '6'}, {'group': '5'}, {'man': '5'}, {'girl': '5'}], 
    'removed ': [{'apple': '5'}, {'makeup': '4'}, {'trash': '4'}, {'stain': '4'}]
}
```

I tried:

```
dic2 = {}
for x, y in dic1_zipped:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

And:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic2= defaultdict( list )
for n,v in dic1_zipped:
    fq[n].append(v)
```

But neither goes deep enough in the dictionary. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have the extra square brackets - in the dic1 your value is a list of a list of tuples, and in dic2 your value is a list of individual dictionaries. Would a better output not be `{'persuaded': {'teacher':6, 'group':5, ...}}`?

Comment: You have a list of lists of tuples?

Comment: @rdodev Yes, that what I have. Do you think it would be easier if I flattened it before converting to a dictionary?

Comment: @user3008918 absolutely. Unless you NEED it, you should flatten the data structure as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following nested dict and list comprehensions will do it for you:

```
dic2 = {key: [{k: v} for sublist in value for k, v in sublist] for key, value in dic1.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> {key: [{k: v} for sublist in value for k, v in sublist] for key, value in dic1.items()}
{'removed ': [{'apple': '5'}, {'makeup': '4'}, {'trash': '4'}, {'stain': '4'}], 'persuaded ': [{'teacher': '6'}, {'group': '5'}, {'man': '5'}, {'girl': '5'}]}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{'persuaded ': [{'teacher': '6'}, {'group': '5'}, {'man': '5'}, {'girl': '5'}],
 'removed ': [{'apple': '5'}, {'makeup': '4'}, {'trash': '4'}, {'stain': '4'}]}
```

I am actually surprised you didn't want to have *one* dictionary per value:

```
dic2 = {key: {k: v for sublist in value for k, v in sublist} for key, value in dic1.items()}
```

which produces:

```
>>> {key: {k: v for sublist in value for k, v in sublist} for key, value in dic1.items()}
{'removed ': {'stain': '4', 'trash': '4', 'apple': '5', 'makeup': '4'}, 'persuaded ': {'group': '5', 'teacher': '6', 'man': '5', 'girl': '5'}}
>>> pprint(_)
{'persuaded ': {'girl': '5', 'group': '5', 'man': '5', 'teacher': '6'},
 'removed ': {'apple': '5', 'makeup': '4', 'stain': '4', 'trash': '4'}}
```

Comment: user has a list of lists of tuples, so this wolution wouldn't work.

Comment: @rdodev: Note the `value[0]` and most of all, the demo. It works just fine. In any case, I updated it to handle more sublists now.

Answer (score 2):

If you get rid of the unnecessary list wrapping, i.e.

```
dic1 = {'persuaded ': [('teacher', '6'), ('group', '5'), ('man', '5'), ('girl', '5')], 'removed ': [('apple', '5'), ('makeup', '4'), ('trash', '4'), ('stain', '4')]}
```

You can do this pretty simply:

```
dic2 = dict((k1, dict(v1)) for k1, v1 in dic1.items())
```

This gives

```
{'persuaded ': {'girl': '5', 'man': '5', 'group': '5', 'teacher': '6'}, 'removed ': {'apple': '5', 'makeup': '4', 'stain': '4', 'trash': '4'}}
```

Which seems more useful than a list of single-entry dictionaries.

(If you can't get rid of the extra level of lists, just use `dict(v1[0])`.)

Comment: Indeed, with the wrapping still in place, this raises a `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required` because `v1` is a list of lists of tuples. You may want to advice the OP on how to make your code work even with the wrapping.

Comment: Thanks, added a clarification for extra list level

Answer (score 0):

```
dict((k, v) for k,v in c1.items())
```